# Slack events subscription url unable to verify, giving 500 error

Tags: python, slack

Slack events subscription url unable to verify giving 500 error

Can someone help why im getting 500 error and how to resolve this , Please find the code im running below

code  events.py

```
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter
from slackclient import SlackClient
import json


tokens = {}
with open('configs.json') as json_data:
    tokens = json.load(json_data)

slack_events_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(tokens.get("slack_signing_secret"), "/slack/events")
slack_client = SlackClient(tokens.get("slack_bot_token"))


@slack_events_adapter.on("message")
def handle_message(event_data):
    message = event_data["event"]
    if message.get("subtype") is None and "BOT TEST" in message.get('text'):
        channel = message["channel"]
        send_message = "Responding to `BOT TEST` message sent by user <@%s>" % message["user"]
        slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel, text=send_message)


@slack_events_adapter.on("error")
def error_handler(err):
    print("ERROR: " + str(err))

slack_events_adapter.start(port=3000)
```

config.json

```
{
  "slack_bot_token":"xoxb-527557105879-949546657207-***************",
  "slack_signing_secret":"ab6ae1405cb4d1db09d***********"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 means tells us theres something wrong with your python script.
**try making this one change in your events.py script**
Your version:

```
@slack_events_adapter.on("message")
def handle_message(event_data):
    message = event_data["event"]
    if message.get("subtype") is None and "BOT TEST" in message.get('text'):
        channel = message["channel"]
        send_message = "Responding to `BOT TEST` message sent by user <@%s>" % message["user"]
        slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel, text=send_message)
```

Change this last line to :
slack_client.chat_postMessage(channel=channel,text=send_message)